# Dual boot Ubuntu and Windows - Keep Ubuntu offline as backup - is it safe?

Tags: ether, bitcoin

If I want to put my Ether (Or any other cryptocurrency for that matter), in an offline backup, is it safe to do it by making a transaction first to an Ubuntu (When it's online at first), and then disable networking there, and use my main machine on Windows with dual boot?
Or, if Windows is connected to the internet, I still compromise the wallet in the Ubuntu installatin even though it's not connected?

Maybe hackers can use the Windows internet connection to do stuff on the Ubuntu somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** disclaimer: I am no security expert, so do not take my word for it - this is merely my opinion.*** That said, here are my 2 cents:
If you do not have any driver/service on your Windows installation to read linux partitions (assuming you are using ext3/4 or similar) then someone who has access to your files from Windows in principle cannot access your wallet files. However, keep in mind that hackers could still install ransomware on your machine, mess with your MBR, wipe your drive etc., and so even if they cannot access your wallet, they might lock you out of it. And obviously, if they had full control over your machine, they could install those drivers and access your linux partition too, although that sounds unlikely. So it's probably a little more secure than having your wallet on your main Windows OS, but definitely less secure than having it on a separate machine.